# Magento2 - Wrong prices in StoreViews

Tags: magento2, price, tax

In my new Magento2 shop (I migrated the data from a Magento 1 instance), I have gross prices for all products in all StoreViews. The Magento1 instance had net prices. I changed all prices from net to gross values and the global tax settings/display after migrating.

The tax calculation and display settings are all based on the scope of the default config. So no special settings for other StoreViews or Websites. All display and calculation settings are set to "Including Tax".

Now comes the part which confuses me for a few days. When I open the shop of the main StoreView (which extends all it's setting from the default scope), I see the gross prices and everything is fine. But when I view the same product another StoreViews I get completely confusing prices. There are no advanced pricings active, no price rules, no other tax display setting for the Store Views. Maybe I am missing some settings, so I hope some experienced Magento people can give me some advice.

Here is a table of what I see in admin and inside the shops for one product. To have a better understanding, I switched the tax display to "including and excluding tax" for testing.

```
|         | Admin | Store frontend (gross) | Store frontend (net) | Store tax | Currency |
|---------|-------|------------------------|----------------------|-----------|----------|
| Store1* | 35.99 |                  35.99 |                31.03 |       16% |   € (DE) |
| Store2  | 32.99 |                  34.13 |                28.44 |       20% |   £ (GB) |
| Store3  | 32.95 |                  34.37 |                28.41 |       21% |   € (NL) |
```

`* Store1 equals the "All Store Views" scope`

I would expect to see the admin values in the Store frontend, but the shop is always showing me the price inside the "Store frontend (gross)" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a setting issue.
For everyone else who has the same problem, try this:

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/tax-cross-border-price.html